# How do I make a game object follow my mouse position with a rigidbody2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started a new game project, and I have tried to find a way to only use a `rigidbody2D` component to move my player game object instead of using `transform.position`. And I can't come up with a good way to do it or find a tutorial or documentation about it.

I have got it to work with `transform.position`, but how could I do it with `rigidbody2D`?

Comment: [tag:unityscript] is a programming language that has been deprecated a long time ago and does not appear in this question. removing the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For movement with RigidBody2D you have mutiple options which are physics based.
I assume that's the reason you want to use RigidBody2D in the first place.

```cs
RigidBody2D obj = GetComponent();

private void moveBody()
{
  //direction towards your goal
  Vector2D v = mousePosition - transform.position;

  //Example 1 set the velocity 
  obj.velocity = v;

  //Example 2 apply force 
  obj.AddForce(v, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

you can read more about RigidBody2D movement
[here](https://www.studytonight.com/game-development-in-2D/right-way-to-move)

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an invisible collider on your stage and move your object to the position you want with the ray.

```
Ray ray;
public RaycastHit hit;

private void Update()
{
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f))
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(Camera.main.transform.position,hit.point);

        transform.position = hit.point;
    }
}
```

Best.